# How to make Travis CI automatically say yes to pip?

Tags: python, travis-ci, pypi

If, in my Travis CI build, I want to uninstall a package locally and install the PyPI version, how do I modify the `.travis.yml` script to automatically say "yes" to the `pip uninstall packagename` command?

As it stands right now, all I have is:

```
- pip uninstall packagename #remove local version
- pip install packagename #install the PyPI version
```

Comment: `pip uninstall` takes [an optional argument `--yes`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall.html#cmdoption-y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into `pip help uninstall` you will see that it takes a `--yes` flag.

Also you could consider using `pip install -U packagename`.